# Connecting to DB through internet

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have SQL Server DB in my computer, attached to my server.  I want to access it through internet.
Please advise what will be the connection string etc. for it.

Comment: you need static IP ..

Comment: static IP is only needed for the server where he's gonna connect , and that's on internet so it is on static IP

Answer (score 1):

is your SQL Server accessible via your local management studio, if yes then you'll use same credentials for your connectionstring to connect to remote server. else you have to configure DNS or firewall options to allow this kind of connection.

Comment: Yes, my SQL server is accessible through the network with which server is connected.  The application is currently running fine over LAN using SQL Server.  I want to use it through internet as well.